# Updating 'through' model's attributes when creating new association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three models `Post`, `Product`, `Mention`

`Product` has many `Posts` through `Mentions`

When I create new association like:

`product.posts << post`

I'd like corresponding `Mention` record to have `created_at` value the same as `post`'s `created_at`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a callback on the `Mention` model

```
after_create :set_created_at

def set_created_at
  self.created_at = self.post.created_at
  self.update
end
```